# Configure SSH for Git - cannot find id_rsa.pub after creating a key

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64, ssh-keys, git-extensions

I am configuring Git to be used with Assembla's remote repository, but I think the same workflow is used with any remote repository, so my question must have a simple generic answer.

Following the docs:

> In Windows, the key pair will appear at C:\Users\name\.ssh by default. In Mac and Linux, it will be in ~/.ssh hidden directory.

I am on Windows, so I looked in my user folder, no `.ssh` folder found (notice I used `/ah` to include hidden files):

```
C:\Users\Victor>dir /ah
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\Users\Victor

09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <DIR>          AppData
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Application Data [C:\Users\Victor\AppData
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Cookies [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Local Settings [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\L
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     My Documents [C:\Users\Victor\Documents]
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     NetHood [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\
09/21/2014  06:39 PM           786,432 NTUSER.DAT
09/21/2014  06:39 PM           262,144 ntuser.dat.LOG1
09/19/2014  06:20 PM                 0 ntuser.dat.LOG2
09/19/2014  06:22 PM            65,536 NTUSER.DAT{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
09/19/2014  06:22 PM           524,288 NTUSER.DAT{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
09/19/2014  06:22 PM           524,288 NTUSER.DAT{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
09/19/2014  06:20 PM                20 ntuser.ini
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     PrintHood [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roamin
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Recent [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\M
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     SendTo [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\M
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Start Menu [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roami
09/19/2014  06:20 PM    <JUNCTION>     Templates [C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roamin
```

When I tried to recreate the key, it says one already exists.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "neolisk@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa): neolisk
neolisk already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? n
```

So where is it then? As a side note, this whole concept of having to generate keys is new to me, as I am coming from SVN world, where authentication is transparent with no client side config needed except for entering user name and password. If there is an option to configure Git without keys, I would appreciate if you could share how to do it.

This may not be relevant to my question, but to keep this in context of software development, I am using Visual Studio 2008 with [Git Source Control provider from Codeplex](https://gitscc.codeplex.com/) and [git extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). I did not find a way to set this up inside the IDE, this is why I am playing with command line here. Local commits were working fine, this came up when I decided to link with remote. If there is a way to configure it within the IDE, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Try it from the git bash prompt instead of windows command prompt

Comment: @AndrewC: I tried, it created another one (for some reason did not offer to overwrite), but the .ssh folder is still not there. When I tried for the second time, if offered to overwrite, same as before. Could be that 32-bit/64-bit problem. Anyway, same issue.

Comment: When you used git bash did it have something like /users/YOURNAME/ in the "Enter file in Which.." prompt or was it still "//.ssh"

Comment: @AndrewC: This time it was `/c/Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of `//.ssh`.

Comment: "Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/andrew/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/c/Users/andrew/.ssh'." - For me it creates the directory no problem (visible from explorer and command prompt).  You may want to go to the root of your filesystem and search for 'id_rsa.pub'

Comment: @AndrewC: I used FAR manager, and searched from the C: root, it did not find anything. I tested it previously with pagefile.sys (a hidden file), which it found in no time, and also a file under a hidden folder. It may sound dumb, but can you make a screenshot of how it looks on your machine? I have no idea what I am missing here, but perhaps this can give some clue... I am using Windows 7, what's your OS version?

Comment: @AndrewC: If it helps, I tried disabling UAC, then after restart my key was not there. I figured this because it did not prompt to overwrite. But it didn't create the `.ssh` folder either. Must be some temporary folder that it's working with, to which I don't have access (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the environment variable HOME is defined to C:\Users\Victor

Second, when you see `Enter file in which to save the key (/C/Users.Victor/.ssh/id_rsa):`, simply hit <kbd>return</kbd>, and it will create the right files.

I prefer using Git in a cmd session, after launching [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), which does set `HOME` properly.

Comment: +1 and accepting. Worked perfectly. Set HOME, don't supply the name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is the output log from a successful run of `ssh-keygen` command (same results when running inside git bash or command prompt):

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsa):
/c/Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/Victor/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx neolisk@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

> Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):

just press Enter without enter your filename

Comment: Hi! This is too small/incomplete to be an answer, it would be better as a comment on the question